# Making a UITabController the tab of another UITabController

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

Is it possible to have one UITabController be a tab of another UITabBarController? For example, I have a UITabController with 6 tabs, can I make the the sixth tab lead to a UITabBarController with two tabs?

Answer (score 2):

You mean the 5th tab, since if you try to put 6 tabs in a UITTabBarController, you will wind up with a "More" selection, and then those tabs showing up in the tableview.

I imagine this could be done using either Storyboards with Container Views, or using parent/child view controllers in code. The question is: why would you? You'd then have a tab bar on top of another tab bar. You're pretty much guaranteed rejection by Apple because I don't believe this is allowed by the HIG.

If you need more than 5 buttons worth of tabs, either implement a custom solution, or change your UI/UX to something like a split view controller with master/detail lists - something more scalable of an interface.